Simple modules of the Weyl algebra
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and W be the Weyl algebra, as the algebra over $\mathbb{F}$ generated by $a,b$ with relation $ab-ba=1$.
The description of simple modules over the Weyl algebra over algebraically closed fields of characteristic p is known, they have dimension p over F and they are in one to one correspondence with the pair of matrices of the form
$$M_a:=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & ... & \mu \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}, \quad M_b:=\begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda & p-1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & \lambda & p-2 & ... & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & \lambda & ... & 0 \\
    \vdots & \vdots  & \vdots & \vdots & 1  \\
    0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix}$$
for $\mu,\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$.
Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the field of $p$ elements and assume that $M$ is a module such that the action of $a$ and $a$ is invertible. Then, condition $ab-ba=1$ implies that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}}(M)$ is a multiple of p. So, assume that $\dim_{\mathbb{F}}(M)=p$. Is it true that if $M$ is simple then $M$ is given by a pair of matrices as above?

For algebraically closed $\mathbb F$, the answer is yes, according to https://ferngaston.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/representations-of-the-weyl-algebra/ . For $\mathbb F = \mathbb Z_p$, I suspect that is no, since I don't think the eigenvalues have to lie in $\mathbb Z_p$.

The answer to your particular question is Yes.
First of all, whether you have representation over $\mathbb F_p$ you have a representation over it's algebraic closure. First claim that whether you suppose $\dim M = p$ then it is simple over algebraic closure $\mathbb F$. The reason for that is that dimension $p$ is minimal possible so over algebraic closure it's impossible to have non-trivial submodule.
Next claim is that the eigenvalue of $M_b $ lies in $ \mathbb F_p $ in that case. The characteristic polynomial equals to $(x -\lambda)^p$. So $\lambda^p \in \mathbb F_p$ thus $\lambda \in \mathbb F_p$.
Fix the basis over algebraic closure $e_1, \dots, e_p$ for which $M_a$, $M_b$ has desired form. I claim that $e_i$ are in $\mathbb F_p$ (up to constant).
First of all $e_1$ is unique (up to constant) eigenvector for $M_b$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ from $\mathbb F_p$. So it could be chosen as $\mathbb F_p$ vector. Then $e_2, \dots, e_p$ are also $\mathbb F_p$ vectors, as they are of the form $M_a^k e_1$. Then $\mu$ also in $\mathbb F_p$. So the matrices in basis $e_1, \dots, e_p$ has desired form.
Although the converse, that all simple modules has dimension p, is not true because if one do not restrict dimension, $M_b$ could have more than one eigenvalue, all of them lying outside $\mathbb F_p$.
